# CSS ERRORS at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I received 3 errors in the following code;

```
<style media="screen">
.sqs-audio-embed{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

`Error 1: at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)`

`Error 2: { expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected)`

`Error 3: at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)`

This is the entire .css file

```
div {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 200px;
}

.post-content{
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

.thumbnail{
    position: relative;
}

<style media="screen">
.sqs-audio-embed{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.root{
    --main-bg-color: brown;
}
```

I tried to search for a solution but I had no luck. Can someone explain these errors and explain how to correct them?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Why do you have a random <style media="screen"> in the middle of your css?

Comment: You can't put HTML in the middle of your CSS. If you want to add a media query to a stylesheet then use [the CSS syntax for media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and not the HTML syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You said it's in ".css" file. `<style>` is an html element, so you should not use it inside css file. I think you should use media queries instead, something like this:

```
@media screen {
    .sqs-audio-embed {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

please refer [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#targeting_media_types) for more information.